# Long boot due to dhcpclient running on unplugged cable - Kubuntu 21.10

Tags: boot, ethernet, dhcp

Boot takes over a minute because dhcpclient is running even with cable unplugged.

Before anything loads I get lots of messages like:
[image: boot dhcp]

Things I tried:

- putting on /etc/network/interfaces:

```
  allow-hotplug enp42s0
```

- on /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf uncommented and changed value of settings:

```
  timeout 5;
  
  retry 0;
```

- my /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml:

```
  network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    enp42s0:
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp6: true
      optional: true
```

- tried setting static ip on /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml:

```
  network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp42s0:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [192.168.1.222/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
```

This not only doesn't work as also my connection to my cellphone with usb tether doesn't work anymore. Changed back renderer to NetworkManager and my usb connection is up again

Comment: Is Network Manager running? Is the behavior the same either with or without NM?

Comment: Yes, NetworkManager is running. And as I said, I changed to networkd and it didn't help at all.

Comment: I suggest that you revert all the changes and return netplan to its default and see if the problem persists. If it does, let's see what is failing within NM.